# Which is more Efficient? regex on long string or list

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regex to look for matches.  Is it more efficient to use it on a long string or that same string broken up into a list?

For Example

```
mystring = "asdfl;jkasdfj;ldj;lj;dlskjfasdfjkl; ;lj ;lf ak;lkjf al;kjdlkjsdl;fkja;dlkjf a;lsdf"
```

OR

```
mylist = ["asdfl;jkasdfj;ldj;lj;dlskjfasdfjkl;",";lj", ";lf ak;lkjf","al;kjdlkjsdl;fkja;dlkjf a;lsdf"]
```

Comment: Just write down your actual problem and profile it. Guessing performance is just wrong.

Comment: The performance entirely depends on the actual strings your matching and the regex you're using. If your regex matches inefficiently and backtracks a lot, it might be faster throwing it at chopped-up strings, if not, it might be just the other way around. No point in guessing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simpler and more efficient way, because of how the `re` module is written, is to use the regex on the string. This isn't definitively faster, but it's far more efficient because it's easier to code, easier to maintain, and makes better use of Python's included batteries.

`re` is optimized for long strings, not lists. If you were to use a regex on that list of strings, you'd end up making quite a few calls to the functions in `re`.

Basic rule, don't make optimizations unless they're necessary because the existing way of doing it is too slow.

Comment: this is decent advice for optimizations in general, but it would be better to consider the computational complexity of regular expression matching to get an idea.  For instance, if re matching was exponential on the size of input, it would be better to break it up.  that isn't true though, see my answer below.

Comment: @KarlR hence why I say `re` is optimized for long strings, not lists of short strings. Not to mention that complexity isn't everything, practical considerations (in this case) are just as important.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [theoretical computational complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times) of regular expression matching, it should take at most O(n*m) where n is the length of the input, and m is the size of the regular expression.  This suggests breaking up the input will have no advantage since you will either be adding up pieces of n to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

What you really should do, instead of listening to random people on SO take a stab at guessing, is to actually measure the differences.

Use the excellent `timeit` module to do this. [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html). Example code:

```
import timeit
from mymodule import list_func, string_func

print 'list version:', timeit.timeit(list_func)
print 'string version:', timeit.timeit(string_func)
```

Comment: The advice people give on SO is indeed good, but profiling is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you posted using a long string is better. The list doesn't seem to contain any logic, which would define the search criterion, so you would need to match/search in the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

Questions such as 'which is more efficient' are best answered by profiling. So profile both the cases and see which is faster. That said, small differences should not really matter right? But Rafe is right. `re` and strings go along much better.

Comment: yea, I was thinking about doing that...I'm going to be matching with really long strings, thats why I was curious